# Update project to Android M compatible

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this might be a easy question to some people, but i been googling this for this entire afternoon and try to find out how to set up the `build.gradle` file in my Android project.

I am updating some APIs and making them ready to Android M. Now everything is fine now. However, i got confused about the `minSdkversion`,`targetSdkversion`,`complieSdkVersion`.

My current setup is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'   //this was 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 'MNC'   //this was 21
    ...
}
...

}
```

As you can see from the comments, my app was complied and target API21 before and now i change it to `MNC` in order to cover the whole range from `api11`to `MNC`.

This is my test cases,

Device with Android M(API22)---OK

Device with Android 5.1.1 (API22)---error and FAILED_OLDER_SDK

If i change my setup to

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...
}
```

Test cases,

Device with Android M(API22)---OK

Device with Android 5.1.1(API22)---OK

Device with Android 4.3.1(API18)---OK //Why is this OK?

if device with API18 can run the project complied against 21, then why the Android 5.1.1(API22) couldn't run the project complied against MNC?

Comment: May i understand what would be your suggestion to cover up to from 11 to MNC at this moment? i did flash the custom rom on my machine already, but for another 5.1.1 device, i wonder why it is not covered in the range from 11 to MNC?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, since Android M is still in developer preview, any app that targets MNC will only run in emulators or devices with the MNC developer preview.